# Remove dynamically added element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to remove a stylesheet that is dynamically being added to the end of `<head>` tag

For some reasons, i'm forced to use javascript to remove that stylesheet tag and add my own

here is the code i tried -

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('link[href^="somepath/editor.css"]').remove();
jQuery('head').append("<link href='somepath/custom/editor.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' />");
});
```

the problem is that this function is being executed before the CkEditor functions. So my Stylesheet is being added before the ckeditor stylesheet and the ckeditor stylesheet
I tried using `.load` instead of `.ready` but then the code doesn't seem to run at all.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know when the css will be added you can use setInterval to poll for it.

```
var interval = setInterval(function(){
    var css = jQuery('link[href^="somepath/editor.css"]')
    if (css.length){
        css.remove();
        jQuery('head').append("<link href='somepath/custom/editor.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' />");
        clearIntrval(interval);
    }
}, 500);
```